# js format string to pretty url

Tags: javascript

since I'm not so proficient in js so I apologize in advance for a possibly unnecessary question, but as with js, rewrite plain text to pretty url.

So this:
hello world

To this:
hello-world

And then insert the rewritten form into the form input

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Nadpis</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="{{ old('title') }}" required minlength="3" maxlength="80" onblur="this.form.url.value=this.value"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="url">URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" class="form-control" value="{{ old('url') }}" required minlength="3" maxlength="80" readonly/>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is `old('url') supposed to be and can we just replace it with the new version?

Comment: This is not pure html. But about the blade function

Comment: Updated my answer to handle unwanted chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your problem, i hope this code helps you

```js
function prettyUrl(value)
{
  return value.replace(/ /g, "-").replace(/@/g, "").replace(/\$/g, "").replace(/!/g, "").replace(/#/g, "").toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Nadpis</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" required minlength="3" maxlength="80" onblur="this.form.url.value=prettyUrl(this.value)" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="url">URL</label>
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" class="form-control" required minlength="3" maxlength="80" readonly/>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Updated**
replace special character with Nothing and lowercase all letters

Comment: Thanks, now I still treat the special characters, but I can handle it. I was looking for useless science

Comment: also you can use encodeURI(uri) for convert your Title to string that valid for Url

Comment: encode uri passes the following characters: ; , /? : @ & = + $ - _. ! ~ * '() #

This is undesirable for me. I require rewriting spaces to hyphens, only lowercase letters and without any special character. Which I've already done

Comment: you can write .replace sequence for replace all special characters , I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

- Add event listeners
- Execute on load if needed
- Remove inline event handlers
- Perform a replace before URIEncoding

Change `encodeURIComponent(this.value.replace(/ /g, "-"))`
to `this.value.replace(/ /g, "-")` if you just want the replace

Additionally we could use new URL() and [URL SearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) on the result if it is supposed to be an actual URL

```js
//const re1 = /[\;\,\/\?\:\@\&\=\+\$\_\.!\~\*\'\(\)\#]/g
const re2 = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g

window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  const title = document.getElementById("title"); // store the field
  title.addEventListener("input", function() { // on any input 
    document.getElementById("url").value = encodeURIComponent(
      // this.value.replace(/ /g, "-").replace(re1,"") // left out the "-"
      this.value.replace(re2,"").replace(/ /g, "-") // using re 2
    ); // encode after replace
  });
  title.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); // trigger the change
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title">Nadpis</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="Hello world;,/?:@&=+$_.!~*'()#" required minlength="3" maxlength="80" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="url">URL</label>
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" class="form-control" value="What is the old URL?" required minlength="3" maxlength="80" readonly/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this replace code to format your Pretty URL:

```
var prettyUrl = oldUrl.split(' ').join('-');
```